# Why 'model' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to add a radioselect in my admin panel **only**. I use a many to many field in order to connect objects of another model (Background).

*What I have now :* The radio select is here and works on the admin panel, but I get this error when I proceed and save the changes : `'Background' object is not iterable`.

How can I save and keep the information as selected ?

MyApp/**models.py**

```
class Background(models.Model):
    bk_color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

class FormOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    background = models.ManyToManyField(Background, blank=True)
    ...
```

MyApp/**forms.py**

```
class FormOneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormOne
        fields = ['name', 'background']

    background = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Background.objects.all(), required=False)
```

MyApp/**admin.py**

```
class FormOneAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'background']
    form = FormOneForm


site.register(Background)
site.register(FormOne, FormOneAdmin)
```

I couldn't debug the problem, I'd be glad to know from where it is coming and how I can resolve it ?

EDIT :

Added TraceBack :

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  618.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1521.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1470.                 self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in save_related
  1102.         form.save_m2m()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save_m2m
  102.                 f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in save_form_data
  2603.         setattr(instance, self.attname, data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in __set__
  1266.         value = tuple(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/multistepform/formone/75/
Exception Value: 'Background' object is not iterable
```

Comment: please post full stacktrace.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I added the track trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `radio widget` to create **many to many** relationship, because django is expecting an array of `background` id (that's what django complains in your stack trace) instead of a single `background` id when you posting data to the `FormOneAdmin` add view.

You can comment out the line of `ModelChoiceField` and you will get it to work.

```
class FormOneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormOne
        fields = ['name', 'background']

    # background = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Background.objects.all(), required=False)
```

Or if you still need to let only zero or one `Background` object bind to a `FormOne` object, you should use `ForeignKey` instead of `ManyToManyField`. And the code would look like this:

```
class FormOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    # background = models.ManyToManyField(Background, blank=True)
    background = models.ForeignKey(Background, blank=True) # <-- use foreign key instead


class FormOneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FormOne
        fields = ['name', 'background']

    background = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=Background.objects.all(), required=False)


class FormOneAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name', 'background']
    form = FormOneForm
```